# HTML5 Player works on local system but not on server

Tags: html, video

I am using an HTML5 player and the videos work perfectly on my local machine but once I upload everything to the webserver the video will not load. No error message. Just an X

All the paths are perfect (I triple checked)

It works in Chrome and Opera but not firefox or IE :(

```
  <source src="http://mywebsite.com/english_short.webmvp8.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
  <source src="http://mywebsite.com/english_short.theora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
  <!-- Flash Fallback. Use any flash video player here. Make sure to keep the vjs-flash-fallback class. -->
  <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="150" height="130" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["http://mywebsite.com/screen.png", {"url": "http://mywebsite.com/english_short.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
    <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
    <img src="oceans-clip.png" width="150" height="130" alt="Poster Image"
      title="No video playback capabilities." />

  </object>
</video>
```

Comment: also, some code would be nice.

Comment: Sorry. I'm still getting used to this site.

Comment: That's alright. :) 1) Go to your profile 2) scroll down to your questions. 3) click on one 4) find the best answer. 5) click the check mark answer thingy.

Comment: i know you checked the path, but try using fiddler or a similar tool to make sure your files are getting there

Comment: fiddler? Getting where? on the server? I used filezilla

Comment: I know the files are on the server because entered the exact path in the address bar and it tried to download them

Comment: ah i see. hm. it just seems like maybe they're blocked or somethign.

Comment: I even added 777 permissions to the files/folders

Comment: I just realized that it works in Chrome and Opera but not firefox or IE :(

Answer (score 0):

It's your video types.  WebM and Ogv aren't supported by IE. Firefox is supposed to support WebM; but only in version 4. to target IE, you'll need to use MPEG or AVI.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues before with versions of Firefox before 4.0 where the OGG source had to be the first one otherwise it fails. As mentioned by Thomas, FF 4 should support WEBM, but I'd suggest putting the OGG source first, followed by the WEBM.

As for IE, again as Thomas says, it supports playing MP4 through a Flash player as you have done so.

Can you link us to a test page?